# How to put a text field after ListTile in Expanded?

Tags: flutter, dart

On the page I have a list, at the bottom of the pagination, which is displayed with buttons (1, 2, 3...). Each page has 10 items. It is necessary that in each list on each page when scrolling down there is a text field. How can I insert it? In my code example I have an error: RenderFlex overflowed. I want the text field to be at the end of the list.  My code:

```js
body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 24),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: ...,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                 ...
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: TextField(),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38),
        child: PaginationWidget(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of your `PaginationWidget` ?

Comment: There's too much code in there. It is not needed for layout, just button pagination, which should be after Expanded so that it is on top of the list on the screen. And when 10 elements scroll down, there should be a text field at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

hello dear friend if you want to put after **each** listile a textfield you can return a **column** in **itembuilder** then put your childeren in there

like this

```
body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 24),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.separated(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: ...,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return column(
                  childeren: [
                     ListTile(
                         ...
                        ),
                     textfield(),
                 ],
              );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const Divider();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: TextField(),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38),
        child: PaginationWidget(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: That's not what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove the `Expanded()` widget from your code, that's just going to stretch your listview to the height and width of your screen.

Next wrap your column with `SingleChildScrollView()` widget to make your listview, textfield, and pagination widget scrollable.

After, add a  `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` physics in your listview.

Your code should look like this:

```dart
body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, bottom: 24),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  ListView.separated(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: ...,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        ...,
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const Divider();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: TextField(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38, right: 38),
                child: PaginationWidget(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I need Expanded in order for the paination to be visible all the time, so that it is above the list. Now, as you wrote, I need to scroll to it, it is below

Comment: So you want the `PaginationWidget` to be above the ListView? Or you want it in a fixed position at the bottom of the screen?